# ExpandableListView inside NestedScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fragment with an expandable list view which should be scrollable if the content is larger than the remaining screen. However, I cannot find a way to get the scrolling working properly. Here's the fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titleView"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="9dp" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        />
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to wrap a LinearLayout around the NestedScrollView (because some other post said that), but it did not work. When I open an element at the bottom of the list it scrolls down to show the complete child in the view, but the view does not respond to any scrolling attempts, neither by sliding up/down on the items nor clicking on the scroll bar.

Adapter code taken 1:1 from here: http://developine.com/expandable-listview-android-kotlin/ only xml is changed as shown above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't understand why is **ExpandableListView** wrapped in the **NestedScrollView**. If you don't have an exact reason for this - remove **NestedScrollView**
2. If you need to keep the **NestedScrollView** - I think Your list isn't scrolling, because the ScrollView consumes touch events. You could try to make a custom ExpendableListView that disallows to intercept the touch event.

**Kotlin (if you're using java then change it to java code):**

```
class MyOwnExpendableListView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ExpandableListView(context, attrs) {

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

Then use it in your xml:

```
<MyOwnExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
/>
```

Comment: If I don't use the NestedScrollView, how can I enable scrolling on the ExpendableListView? When I use it without the NestedScrollView the content just extends beyond the screen. I would love to have it working without the NestedScrollView. (That's why I looked up how to make views scrollable and ended up using NSV around it)

Comment: Ok, I found the error. The fragment was not correctly set up which lead to the ExpandableListView thinking that it can extend beyond the screen and thus correctly not scrolling. Removing the NSV and setting the constraints, width and height from the NSV in the ExpandableListView does the trick. Thanks @Mwasz for pointing out the NSV is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my question which solves the problem but as pointed out by @Mwasz **this should not be the way you do it**. So I document it here just for reference and maybe if somebody has really a reason to use the NestedScrollView

In the `ExpandableListView` add

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

to enable the scrolling inside the NestedScrollView.